# How can I completely clear just one branch in a git repo?

Tags: git

I have a prototype version of an app in a repo.

I'd like to store the code from this prototype for future reference but not include any of the files in the next release version of the code which I'll start form scratch on a new branch.

So far, I've created a new branch for the prototype and pushed that to our remote repository - that's safe and not going anywhere.

Back on my local, master branch I'd like to start with a completely clean slate - remove all the files currently listed.

Is there a more gitish way to approach this than simply removing the files?

I remember there was a method I used previously when setting up github pages for a repository but the documentation for that seems to have moved :/

Thanks in advance

Comment: Here's a blog [post](http://madduck.net/blog/2007.07.11:creating-a-git-branch-without-ancestry/) on creating a branch without ancestry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a [blog post](https://web.archive.org/web/20170918130215/http://madduck.net/blog/2007.07.11%3acreating-a-git-branch-without-ancestry/) on creating a branch without ancestry. It describes two possible ways, you can try both and see which one works better for you.

*In summary now that the original link is dead:*

The simplest method of creating a new git branch without any ancestors:

```
$ echo ref: refs/heads/newbranch > .git/HEAD
$ git branch
  master
[...]
$ git commit -m 'creating newbranch'
$ git branch
  master
* newbranch
```

Another option is:

```
$ git symbolic-ref HEAD refs/heads/newbranch
[...]
```

Which doesn't touch any files in `.git`

Comment: Please include the actual answers in your answer. Link-only answers are generally frowned on.

Comment: I think it's completely ok, because the blog post answers the question. I don't see any reason for copy-pasting it here.

Comment: Well, I read it as well as the comments to the answer. And I totally agree with Jon Skeet and Tom Ligda. So, I'd rather leave this answer as is. The OP got his solution, so my answer was accepted. If you think you can improve it with a little exerpt from the linked blog post, go ahead.

Comment: FWIW, the link is broken now.

Comment: 4 years later someone in the comments is thinking: "I told you"