# How can I start a clean branch with no ancestry, then commit files progressively?

Tags: git, branch

I have a PHP framework versioned with GIT and I'm planning several (drastic) changes to its core.

What I want to do is to start working on the new core in a new branch, but since this change might require some restructuring on the filesystem too, I'd like to start this new branch as cleanly as possible.

I want the clean branch to include only with the core files. As I'm finishing my changes, I want to add the rest of the modules from the framework to the working directory one by one, but keep the ability to merge if I do changes on master.

How can I do that?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I completely clear just one branch in a git repo?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11313514/how-can-i-completely-clear-just-one-branch-in-a-git-repo)

Comment: These questions have some similarities, but they are not exact duplicates.

Answer (score 140, accepted):

#### Branch with No Ancestors

You want the **--orphan** flag. For example:

```
git checkout master
git checkout --orphan foo

# Unstage all the files in your working tree.
git rm --cached $(git ls-files)
```

will create a new branch named *foo* with no ancestors, but it will preserve the current working tree from whatever branch you were on when you called the command (in this case, the *master* branch). You can then modify your working tree to suit, and then make a commit to start that branch's history afresh.

#### Incremental Staging of Files

To perform incremental additions to your history, use `git add` to stage just the files you want for each commit. The git-add(1) manual page has this to say about adding files selectively:

> Fileglobs (e.g. *.c) can be given to add all matching files. Also a leading directory name (e.g.  dir to add dir/file1 and dir/file2) can be given to add all files in the
>   directory, recursively.

Comment: Thank you @CodeGnome,it looks pretty interesting, I just want to add one more question:

lets say I create this new _foo_ branch, add some folder from master and do my changes. If in the future I do a change on master, can I merge it with _foo_?

Comment: You can treat an orphaned branch like any other branch when it comes to merging, cherry-picking, or checking out individual files from another branch into *foo* (e.g. `git checkout master -- quux`). The only real difference is that the orphaned branch won't have an initial commit until you make one, and git will need to perform merges without reference to ancestry.

Comment: then delete `rm -rf * .*`

Comment: @wieczorek1990 That will delete the `.git` folder.. Use `git clean -fd ` instead.

Comment: +1 for `git rm --cached $(git ls-files)` . very important when you want to set up a documentation branch. You don't want all the changes of the ancestor. Plus it's noteworthy that you can only see the orphan branch after you added and committed !

Answer (score -4):

If you must work with an old version of git:

```
 mkdir some_dir
 cd some_dir
 git init
 echo a>some_file; git add some_file; git commit -m 'initial commit'
 cd ..
 git fetch ./some_dir/ master:new_independent_branch
 rm -rf some_dir
```

Comment: There is a systematic approach. Hacks don't last long.

Answer (score -5):

What you can do is simply moving to a new branch, `git co -b my_new_branch`, clean up your code and keep the things you need, and finally commit. That commit, the first on `my_new_branch`, would then be a *clean* one.

Comment: yeah but my worry is how to merge the future changes on the files that I do on master with the same files on my new branch when I already added them.