# Git repo for a branch

Tags: git, github

Can I initialize a new repo for a branch? I tried the git init command and got this message:

```
Reinitialized existing Git repository in /Users/UserNameRedacted/workspace/twitter_clone/.git/
```

Answer (score -1):

You want `git checkout --orphan nameOfBranch`.

See: [A duplicate question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11487811/how-can-i-start-a-clean-branch-with-no-ancestry-then-commit-files-progressively)